# Relativity of an object moving away from me

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

If I am standing still, and a car is driving away from me at a constant speed. What would the relativistic effects be?  Would it appear to move slower as it got farther away?  With each second would I be seeing farther back in time when compared to the cars current location?

Answer (score -1):

For one, we can look at and compare the clocks. The moving frame (the car) will seem to have their clock run slower than ours, who are standing still. And vice versa, our clock will appear to be running fast w/respect to the clock inside the moving frame.
Another effect will be with lengths, parallel to the motion of the car. To the stationary observer (us) they will appear contracted.
One more - the mass of the moving car should be getting larger.
All of this explained in detail here, for instance:
[Time dilation/length contraction etc](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html)

Comment: This does not sound quite correct. To us, the moving clock in the car will appear to run slow. To the passengers in the car, our clock will appear to run slow.

Comment: $T_0\gamma$ true